# "figure.max_open_warning" in pyplot... "May consume too much memory"

Tags: python, matplotlib, memory

My script works, but when running I receive the error that is displayed in the heading.  I do not understand why bc I use `plt.clf()` after every plot that I open and save.  Below is an example of one of the instances I open (and close) a figure

...

```
            roi1 = img[700:830, 730:835]
        roiStats1(roi1)
        plt.imshow(roi1)
        plt.colorbar()
        plt.savefig('roi1_'+file[:20]+'.tif')
        plt.clf()

        ###### Make ROI sequential to be able to "bin" the axes #############
        roi1y =roi1.reshape(13650, 1)
        roi1y_df = pd.DataFrame(roi1y).reset_index().rename(columns= {0: 'Intensity'})

        ###### Plot Y axis variation of ROI for edge or lane gradient ###########
        inlet_bins = np.linspace(-1, 13650, num=10, endpoint=True)
        y_binlabels = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
        roi1y_df['bins'] = pd.cut(roi1y_df['index'], inlet_bins, labels = y_binlabels)
        roi1y_df['Intensity'] = roi1y_df['Intensity'].astype(float)
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        sns.boxplot(x='bins', y='Intensity', data=roi1y_df, ax = ax).set_title('Y-Axis Variation'+file[:20])
        plt.savefig('YvarPlot_Inlet_'+file[:20]+'.tif')
        plt.clf()
```

...

So I `plt.clf()` each time I open and save a figure, but I still get the memory warning

Answer (score 0):

try plt.close() instead of plt.clf()